# Problems using WHERE and HAVING together in a T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

OK, I keep on getting this wrong and have tried it many different ways for a couple of hours now.  Hope someone can help.

I am trying to query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns` to find:

1. All tables that only contain 2 columns
2. That the name of those 2 columns both end with "ID"

Here is my query:

```
select table_name, count(column_name) as [Count]
from information_schema.columns 
where column_name like '%id'
group by table_name 
having count(column_name) = 2
```

But, it's not returning correct results.  You can run it on your own database (I am sure many databases out there have tables with columns whose names end with `ID`) and see for yourself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What would be the `not returning correct results` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the `LIKE` comparison in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
    table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
GROUP BY table_name 
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN column_name LIKE '%id' THEN column_name END) = 2
    AND count(CASE WHEN column_name NOT LIKE '%id' THEN column_name END) = 0
```

This way only those tables with two columns, wherein said columns should end in `'id'`, will be returned.

Comment: Thanks!  It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select aggregate functions with detail some columns, which not have in group by clause. You can use OVER() clause (window function) in SQL 2005+. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) OVER() AS [Count]
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE table_catalog = 'Database_name' --Database name
      AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%id') A
WHERE [Count] = 2
```

Comment: I will try this out again - it didn't work for me the first time.  Thanks though!